# Issues retrieving facebook social plugin comments for page, C# HttpWebRequest class

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-comments

I'm hoping I've done something knuckle-headed here and there is an easy answer.  I'm simply trying to retrieve the list of comments for a page on my site.  I use the social plug-in and then retrieve the comment id via the edge event.  Server side I send the page id back and do a simple request using a HttpWebRequest.  Worked well back in October, but now I get an 'internal error' response from FB.  I can use the same url string put it into a browser and get the comments back in the browser in json.

```
StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
url.Append("https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=" + comment.page);
string requestString = url.ToString();
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestString) as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Ideas?  Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the Facebook C# SDK (per your tag), try:

```
var url = "{your url}";
var api = new Facebook.FacebookClient(appId,appSec);
dynamic commentsObj = api.Get("/comments/?ids=" + url);
dynamic arrayOfComments = commentsObj[url].data
```